# How do I extract multiple values from each row of a DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a DataFrame `df2` with columns `currencies` and `c_codes`.

Each row in the `currencies` column is a list of one or more dictionaries. I want to extract the value for the key `code` in each dictionary within each list in each row of `currencies` and transfer the `code` values to a different column of the DataFrame `c_codes`

Case in point:

[image: Image 1]

From `df2['currencies'][0]` I want to extract the `code` value `AFN` and transfer it to `df2['c_codes'][0]`

Similarly, if there are multiple `code` values for a row, such as `df2['currencies'][8]` then I want to extract a list of `code` values `['AUD','GBP']` and transfer the list to `df2['c_codes][8]`

Each entry in `c_codes` can be a list for this purpose.

Here's my code:

[image: Image 2]

I have tried using a loop to grab the `code` values in each dict. in each row and append them to a list `temp`. Then append the list `temp` to a bigger list `list_of_currencies` so I get a list with lists of codes corresponding to each row. Then I clear the `temp` list so it can grab the next row of `code` and so on.

However, the code returns the `list_of_currencies` as empty. I have tried playing around with the looping, `temp`, lists, etc. but it just returns empty list or else a list of all appended `codes` without sub-lists.

I want a list returned with sub-lists of `codes` so I can assign each sub-list to a corresponding row in `c_codes` column.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Providing your `DataFrame`s as text not as image would be great. Thanks

Comment: Please avoid posting images of code as that makes it harder to help you. Better try to reduce your problem to a minimal code example with what went wrong and what your expected result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `explode` to expand the list of objects, and `.str` to get the `code` value, for a vectorized (read: really fast) solution:

```
df['c_codes'] = df['currencies'].explode().str['code'].groupby(level=0).agg(list).str.join(', ')
```

Output (based on sample data at the bottom of this answer):

```
>>> df
                                                                                 currencies   c_codes
0                                               [{'code': 'AFN', 'name': 'Afghan afghani'}]       AFN
1                                                         [{'code': 'EUR', 'name': 'Euro'}]       EUR
2  [{'code': 'AUD', 'name': 'Australian dollar'}, {'code': 'GBP', 'name': 'British pound'}]  AUD, GBP
3                                        [{'code': 'XCD', 'name': 'East Carribean dollar'}]       XCD
```

If you want actual lists in the `c_codes` column and not just comma-separate strings, just omit the `.str.join` part:

```
df['c_codes'] = df['currencies'].explode().str['code'].groupby(level=0).agg(list)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                                                                 currencies     c_codes
0                                               [{'code': 'AFN', 'name': 'Afghan afghani'}]       [AFN]
1                                                         [{'code': 'EUR', 'name': 'Euro'}]       [EUR]
2  [{'code': 'AUD', 'name': 'Australian dollar'}, {'code': 'GBP', 'name': 'British pound'}]  [AUD, GBP]
3                                        [{'code': 'XCD', 'name': 'East Carribean dollar'}]       [XCD]
```

---

Sample data for testing above code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'currencies': [
    [{'code':'AFN','name':'Afghan afghani'}],
    [{'code':'EUR','name':'Euro'}],
    [{'code':'AUD','name':'Australian dollar'},{'code':'GBP','name':'British pound'}],
    [{'code':'XCD','name':'East Carribean dollar'}]]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would solve your problem, given that I understood it all correctly:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame({
    "x": ["A", "B", "C"],
    "currencies": [[{"code": "x"}, {"code": "y"}], [{"code": "u"}], [{"code": "v"}]]
})
print(df)
>    x                      currencies
  0  A  [{'code': 'x'}, {'code': 'y'}]
  1  B                 [{'code': 'u'}]
  2  C                 [{'code': 'v'}]


df["c_codes"] = df["currencies"].apply(lambda x: [i["code"] for i in x])
print(df)
>    x                      currencies c_codes
  0  A  [{'code': 'x'}, {'code': 'y'}]  [x, y]
  1  B                 [{'code': 'u'}]     [u]
  2  C                 [{'code': 'v'}]     [v]
```

What this `apply` method does is it iterates over the values in `currencies` and applies the lambda function to it: for each input (in this case a list of dicts) return a list of just the values of each `code` value. These results are then saved to the new column `c_codes`.